# laravel, how to use "whereHas" only with the most recent records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to make a query in which I can get the data of the last records grouped by id, I have a table called "activities" and another called "plants", I need to get all the last activities by plant_id and then move in the relation of that activity
[image]

this is my query

```
$plant=Plant::whereHas('activities.transfers.sections.greenhouses',function($q) use($id){
    $q->groupBy('activities.plant_id')
    ->where('greenhouses.location_id',$id);
    })->get();
```

however, this does not work, I can not do the filtering with the eloquent of only the most recent activities, it seems that eloquent returns all of them

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.. Images will not help us to [reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) most likely your question will be voteclosed..

Comment: Also you should post the real SQL query and not some laraval code which is generating SQL code..

Comment: hi Raymond, ok I'm going to improve my question

Comment: i can most likely help you to figure out the needed SQL code but the eloquent code is where i have to stop, as that have been awhile ago i worked with  laravel and eloquent

Comment: you want to get plants where they have activities in the last day lets say ?

Comment: whereHas('activities.transfers.sections.greenhouses',function($q) use($id){
    $q->where('greenhouses.location_id',$id)->where('created_at',Carbon::now()->subDays(2));
    })->